# Selenium does not detect modalbox with multiple buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code

```
submit.click()
try:            
  element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until
  (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.ID, "continueConfirmation")))
  alert1=driver.switch_to_alert()
  alert1.accept()
except TimeoutException:
  print("no alert")
  driver.close()
```

It gives me no NoAlertexception at alert1.accept() and I m not sure why, i have added the wait, is it because of the the popup dialogbox has two buttons?

Comment: are u sure its an alert? whats continueConfirmation here? is it the id of alert???? if it is den my friend its not an alert it might be a modal dialog or something but not an alert...

Comment: yes correct, its a modal, my bad